# how to transfer string(char*) in kernel into user process using copy_to_user

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I'm making code to transfer string in kernel to usermode using systemcall and copy_to_user
here is my code
kernel

```
     #include<linux/kernel.h>
        #include<linux/syscalls.h>
        #include<linux/sched.h>
        #include<linux/slab.h>
        #include<linux/errno.h>


    asmlinkage int sys_getProcTagSysCall(pid_t pid, char  **tag){


        printk("getProcTag system call \n\n");
         struct task_struct *task= (struct  task_struct*) kmalloc(sizeof(struct task_struct),GFP_KERNEL);

            read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
            task = find_task_by_vpid(pid);

            if(task == NULL )
            {
                    printk("corresponding pid task does not exist\n");
                    read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
                    return -EFAULT;
            }

            read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);

        printk("Corresponding pid task exist \n");  
        printk("tag is %s\n" , task->tag);   
/*
 task -> tag : string is stored in task->tag (ex : "abcde")
          this part is well worked
*/

        if(copy_to_user(*tag, task->tag, sizeof(char) * task->tag_length) !=0) 
            ;

        return 1;
    }


and this is user 

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>


    int main()
    {
        char *ret=NULL;
        int pid = 0;
        printf("PID : ");
        scanf("%4d", &pid);

           if(syscall(339, pid, &ret)!=1)  // syscall 339 is getProcTagSysCall
            printf("pid %d does not exist\n", pid); 
        else
            printf("Corresponding pid tag is %s \n",ret);  //my output is %s = null

        return 0; 
    }
```

actually i don't know about copy_to_user well. but I think copy_to_user(*tag, task->tag, sizeof(char) * task->tag_length) is operated like this code
so i use copy_to_user like above

```
#include<stdio.h>

int re();

void main(){


    char *b = NULL;



    if (re(&b))
        printf("success");

    printf("%s", b);
}


int re(char **str){

    char *temp = "Gdg";
    *str = temp;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a college assignment of some sort?

```
   asmlinkage int sys_getProcTagSysCall(pid_t pid, char  **tag){
```

What is this, Linux 2.6? What's up with ** instead of *?

```
    printk("getProcTag system call \n\n");
```

Somewhat bad. All strings are supposed to be prefixed.

```
     struct task_struct *task= (struct  task_struct*) kmalloc(sizeof(struct task_struct),GFP_KERNEL);
```

What is going on here? Casting malloc makes no sense whatsoever, if you malloc you should have used sizeof(*task) instead, but you should not malloc in the first place. You want to find a task and in fact you just overwrite this pointer's value few lines later anyway.

```
        read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
        task = find_task_by_vpid(pid);
```

find_task_by_vpid requires RCU. The kernel would have told you that if you had debug enabled.

```
        if(task == NULL )
        {
                printk("corresponding pid task does not exist\n");
                read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
                return -EFAULT;
        }

        read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
```

So... you unlock... but you did not get any kind of reference to the task.

```
    printk("Corresponding pid task exist \n");  
    printk("tag is %s\n" , task->tag);
```

... in other words by the time you do task->tag, the task may already be gone. What requirements are there to access ->tag itself?

```
    if(copy_to_user(*tag, task->tag, sizeof(char) * task->tag_length) !=0) 
        ;
```

What's up with this? sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1.

I'm really confused by this entire business.

When you have a syscall which copies data to userspace where amount of data is not known prior to the call, teh syscall accepts both buffer AND its size. Then you can return appropriate error if the thingy you are trying to copy would not fit.

However, having a syscall in the first place looks incorrect. In linux per-task data is exposed to userspace in /proc/pid/. Figuring out how to add a file to proc is easy and left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by making malloc in user

I changed

```
char *b = NULL;
```

to

```
char *b = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100)
```

I don't know why this work properly. but as i guess copy_to_user get count of bytes as third argument so I should malloc before assigning a value

I don't know.  anyone who knows why adding malloc is work properly tell me

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious from the way you fixed it. `copy_to_user()` will only copy data between two memory regions - one accessible only to kernel and the other accessible also to user. It will not, however, handle any memory allocation. Userspace buffer has to be already allocated and you should pass address of this buffer to the kernel.

One more thing you can change is to change your syscall to use normal pointer to char instead of pointer to pointer which is useless.

Also note that you are leaking memory in your kernel code. You allocate memory for `task_struct` using `kmalloc` and then you override the only pointer you have to this memory when calling `find_task_by_vpid()` and this memory is never freed. `find_task_by_vpid()` will return a pointer to a task_struct which already exists in memory so there is no need to allocate any buffer for this.